# How to mock a range-based operator using gmock?

Tags: c++11, googlemock

I have a class that inherits from std::map

```
class LeMap : public std::map<int,int>
{
  ...
};
```

I have another class that is supposed to loop over its elments:

```
class LeMapUser {
  LeMap mMap;
  public:
  void printElements()
  { 
    for( auto& element : mMap ) { whatever(element); }
  }
  private:
  void whatever(int element){ ... }
};
```

Is it possible to mock `LeMap` in order to test `whatever` using gmock ?
Briefly: what operator should I overload to execute the loop?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK a range-based `for` loop needs the `mMap` object to have a `begin()` member which returns an iterator. The iterator needs to have a post-increment operator to walk along the range. Additionally, `mMap` must have an `end()` member, returning a value comparable to the iterator (but not necessarily being an iterator itself).

Comment: thanks. For what I understood it's not so easy to do what I want, but it's not really necessary: one could rework the methods in order to test the calls on the single objects instead of testing the loop itself

Comment: @HAL9000 Yes, sure. I understood you want to test iterating over the map and mock that map but keep iteration. However, if you want to test `whatever(int)` you may just make a series of direct calls to it with any predefined, constant arguments.